# Is it possible to create/manage Roles using a .yaml file?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to secure some REST URLs that are present in my **ApiController.php** so that users with certain privileges can access these REST APIs.
I created some users and assigned them with some Roles using the below link:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/user-concept.html

As you can see, I'm creating roles in Drupal Admin following below steps:

***Drupal UI → People → Role → Add New Role     // line 4***

After that, I added a few permissions in permission.yml:

**xyz.permissions.yml**

```
edit permission:
  title: 'edit permission'
```

And updated routing file to secure APIs:

**xyz.routing.yml**

```
xyz.update:
  path: '/update'
    _controller: 'ApiController::update'
    _permission: 'edit permission'
```

This is working fine. i.e. users that have "edit permission" can access URL "/update". 
But, I don't want to do step on line 4 rather I would like to use some .yaml file to create Roles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User roles are defined in YML files called `user.role.ROLENAME.yml`.

Do a config export (`drush cex`) to get an idea how these files should look like (they will be written to your `config/sync` directory).

Then create your custom role YML files in `my_module/config/install` and they will be created when you enable your module (if you took a YML file from `config/sync` as blueprint, remove the `uuid` and `default_config_hash` keys)

The file should look something like this:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: my_custom_role
label: My custom role
weight: 1234
is_admin: null
permissions:
  - 'do fancy stuff'
```

Comment: This helped a lot! Thanks

Comment: thanks. what does the 'is_admin' do, or where is this documented ?

Comment: @commonpike This is the "super" administrator role thats has ALL permissions enabled by default, without explicitly listing them one by one. E.g. if you install a new module, that super admin role can instantly access everything, without manually adding any new permission from that new module.

Comment: Thanks - still kind of confused, because there is usually only one administrator role - Administrator - is `is_admin` used to create multiple admin roles ? Also, if `is_admin: true` I suppose you don't have to add `permissions`.